# Has Google withdrawn the Tango Constructor app?

Tags: google-project-tango, tango

The Tango Constructor app is referenced in list of Tango tools

[Tango Constructor](https://developers.google.com/tango/tools/constructor)

but it is not available or listed in the Google Play Store, at least in the USA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After several release update on the Tango API,
We had new features, which may not backward compatible with the older version of APKs, we do care about usr experience for customers. we took down TangoConstructor and so other apps which is bad at this time.
Once we have new fix for those apps. it will be back online.
We will let you know once it is available again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question and sent a message to Google. Their reply:

"I have double checked with my team and it appears the app is being updated and it is not because of your country. That is most likely why you're seeing that message"

I think the current version is not compatible to Zaniah so they removed it for now. It is like with "ADF Inspector" which is still available on play store, but when you try to load an ADF, it crashes.

By the way, I'm from Germany and I also see this "not available in your country" message. So it is definitely not because of region restrictions when it is not even available in USA